# Read aloud at start and stop of progress bar (md-progress-linear)

Tags: angularjs, progress-bar, wai-aria, screen-readers, nvda

I need to use NVDA screen-reader to read some messages when a dialog with progress bar appears.

At 0% duration of progress-bar, I need to announce:
**"Your received a timed message"**

At 100% duration of progress-bar:
**"The message expired"**

The progress-bar used is **md-progress-linear**.

The html code looks like below:

```
<md-dialog>
    <md-progress-linear tabindex="0" ng-if="displayProgressIndicator || timeoutValue > 0" md-mode="determinate" class="promptProgressBar" value="{{progressValue}}"></md-progress-linear>
    <md-content class="md-title dialogTitle">
        {{messageTitle}}
    </md-content>
    <md-content class="md-dialog-content">
        {{messageText}}
    </md-content>
    <div class="md-dialog-actions">
        <md-button ng-style="theme.SecondaryButton" ng-click="OnClose()" class="md-primary right">
            {{primaryActionText}}
        </md-button>
        <md-button ng-style="theme.SecondaryButton" ng-if="secondaryActionText.length > 0" ng-click="OnCancel()" class="md-primary right">
            {{secondaryActionText}}
        </md-button>
    </div>
</md-dialog>
```

I saw some [working examples](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/slider/slider-2.html) for slider which uses **aria-valuetext** attribute and NVDA reads those texts properly.

I tried adding **aria-valuetext** attribute in **md-progress-linear** element, but doesn't work.

When the message is arrived, NVDA produces **beep** sounds, but do not read **aria-valuetext**.

Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TL;DR

You can use `aria-live` region to achieve the same

Here is a working codepen :
Output: https://codepen.io/aimt/details/PaaKXM/

Code : https://codepen.io/aimt/pen/PaaKXM/

---

### Refrences

More details available in mdn 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions

and 
https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-live

### Details

Add `<div aria-live="polite" id="livePolite"></div>` to your page

Aria-live is an empty container with aria-live="assertive" or aria-live="polite"

- aria-live="polite" will wait for the screen reader to finish its statement before announcing new content.
- aria-live="assertive" will cut the screen reader off to announce new content.

#### Important

The container **MUST** be present on page load (or you must enforce a JavaScript delay after the aria-live region is added to the DOM before injecting the message into it; 500 milliseconds is usually sufficient, but you should test it). You cannot load an aria-live container with a message already inside it.

The container **MUST** also be empty, to begin with. This is because screen readers will be looking for a change in content in the aria-live container.

#### Behaviour

Screen readers will announce content when content has been injected into the container.

o   Before: `<div aria-live="polite" id="livePolite"></div>`

o   After: `<div aria-live="polite" id="livePolite">Paused Video</div>`

I always keep these on top of my webpage and populate whenever required

`<p aria-live="polite" id="livePolite"></p>
<p aria-live="assertive" id="liveAssertive"></p>`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The demo is working perfect as what I expected. Hence, accepted. But while integrating it in my project, NVDA changes the text of aria-live region but do not announce it. It just beeps. FYI, the dialog appears dynamically. Anything else to do? It is a windows application which is using chromium browser. Can it be a some tab-index issue?

Comment: Is your ``aria-live`` ``<p>`` a part of the web page or is it a part of the dialog?

If it is a part of the dialog, it might not be able to read the live region before the text was injected.

If it is a part of the web page, ensure that the aria-live region is outside the backdrop, I've seen a lot of backdrops adding, aria-hidden = true to stop screen readers from reading items behind the modal.